# Best way to translate "קא"

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, aramaic

In the Aramaic of the Babylonian Talmud, there is a widely used word "קא", like in the sentence והא קא קרי (in [Berahot 13:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=13&format=pdf)).

What is the best way to translate it to Hebrew or English? Or maybe just skip it?

Comment: Off topic......

Comment: @DoubleAA the intention was not purely translating Aramaic, I've asked it for deeper understanding of Talmud texts.

Comment: If Jastrow gave up on translating it you're not likely to get a good answer. Online Jastrow: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/

Comment: @jutky It doesn't matter what you are going to use the translation for. The question is asking for a translation and is thus off topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA, why not cast a closure vote?

Comment: @msh210 I have now. When I first commented though I was pretty sure a mod would just super-vote to close it soon, and I wanted to leave open the possibility of an edit (which would not let me undo my vote). Now it seems less likely for either of those, although the former still perplexes me. Care to comment?

Comment: @msh210 FTR I retain my off-topic vote.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, I'm having second thoughts, myself.

Comment: @DoubleAA +9, still off topic?

Comment: @Yehoshua Score is not related to on-topic-ness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about the Aramaic language; not Judaism. (Were it to relate the interpretation of a particular Talmudic passage, it might be on topic, but in this case the subject of the question is the Aramaic word itself, and the Talmudic context is merely the _motivation_.)

Comment: According to Sokoloff's dictionary, קָא (or קָ־) is a "particle employed before the participle."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Moved from comment section):

The word קא indicates that the action is on-going or in the state of being done. It corresponds to the English prefix a-, which used to be used much more frequently but now is uncommon in the English of the northern United States yet it is still very common in the English of the southern United States.

Here are some examples in English taken from songs and demonstrating all tenses:
1. She was a-rocking and a-rolling.
2. I'm a-coming right now.
3. We will be a-singing and a-dancing all night long.

It has also been incorporated in some words, such as aglow, alight, and afix.

For translating the Aramaic, you could do one of at least three things:

1. Omit it: Its absence won't make that much difference in English. You might, however, need to add something to the translation of the entire passage in order to be clear that the action is or was in the state of being done. For example, "He was reading when something happened" (i.e., you'd add the word 'when' to clarify that the reading was on-going at the time something else happened).
2. Use the Old English / Southern United States prefix:  "He was a-reading, and something happened." (Note that the 'when' can now be changed to 'and' or even omitted and we still understand that the reading was on-going when something happened.)
3. Insert further clarifying words, such as: "He was in the process (or, in the act) of reading (and) something happened." These clauses can also be broken into two seperate sentences, as they often are in Aramaic.

Actually, the fact that the Aramaic often seems to be presenting the narrative as two seperate sentences may be why you'd want to translate it as "in the process of" or something like that. If you omit it, the on-going / concurrent nature of the action is not as strongly emphasized, as in:

1. He was reading. Mar said to him...(whatever he said). In this example, it's not quite as strongly emphasized in the English that he was in the act of reading when Mar said something to him as it is in the Aramaic.

That's why you might want to translate it as:

2. He was in the act of reading. Mar said to him...

Comment: Re southern dialect, that should be "He was a-readin'..."

Comment: So you're saying "לקרות והא קא קרי" means "to read? but he is reading [now]!" ([imperfective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect)) where "לקרות והא קרי" would mean "to read? but he does [=is able to, or often does] read!" ([perfective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfective))? In other words, _ka_ marks the imperfective? (Quotation taken from [_B'rachos_ 13:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=23&size=1), mentioned in the question.)

Comment: @msh210 - I'm sorry I don't understand the terms imperfective and perfective, but I stand by my understanding of קא as indicating that an action is or was on-going. Translation of 13:a - "(You say he must) לקרות read (sh'ma)? (But) this והא (is a case where) he is in the act of reading קא קרי (the passage of sh'ma from the sefer Torah)!" All the stuff in parentheses comes from understanding the entire context of the discussion and is in agreement with how Artscroll and Shteinsaltz understand it and translate it.

Comment: Or, in southern dialect: "He gotta read? But he is a-readin'!"

Comment: @msh210: I just found that the on-line Comprehensive Aramaic Lexicon (CAL) lists קא as an "aspectual modifier with the participle indicating progressive real activity." It doesn't say anything about it being imperfective, and I know enough linguistics to know that I cannot make that determination. Here's a link to CAL: http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/